# HTTP request / response with response from a different server

Tags: scala, http, nginx, clojure

In an HTTP request/response scenario, I guess it doesn't matter to the client who responds to the requests (how would he tell anyway).

In short, I want to go from this :

```
Client
 ↓   ↑
 Nginx
  ↓   ↑
  ServerA
   ↓   ↑
   ServerB
```

To this :

```
Client
 ↓    ↑
 Nginx ↖
  ↓      ↖
  ServerA  ↖
   ↓      ↗
   ServerB
```

Since serverB already has the response and no additional treatment will be done, I would like to bypass the serverA, but should go through nginx if possible (to use compression for instance).

Specifically I would like to know more about :

- the nginx configuration necessary (if any)
- does the protocol exchange between serverA and ServerB has to be special ?
- the context that has to be passed around for this to happen ? Also, what happens if they use different languages (in my case Clojure and Scala).

A small sample example would be **very** welcome (preferably Clojure, Scala, Java, Node.js - any language as long as it's readable).

Comment: Why would you need to bypass ServerA in the return trip? It would seem like the demands must be really extreme to make this worthwhile.

Comment: @acjay (1) the context is real-time telecommunications with complex routing (2) there are potentially many servers in the chain (which also potentially makes them wait for the answer).

Comment: It's going to be tough to implement. You're basically describing a custom implementation of non-standard HTTP that externally still looks like HTTP. It's probably possible, but I think you'll be opening a Pandora's box by doing so.

Comment: @acjay I'm all ears :D seriously.

Comment: I've never done anything nearly like this, but it sounds like you need completely custom input and output to your system. Not sure you can do this with Nginx, because you need something that will hold the TCP connection with the client open until it gets a response from someplace else (but Nginx could sit in front of that). You'll need your own protocol internally to implement the unidirectional data flow between services (maybe Akka would do). You might either pass all the context along at all steps, or have the edge service remember it. That's the best I got! I'm out of my depth here.

Comment: @acjay I had roughly the same ideas of using a message broker (Akka or anything really). I was hoping that if the context from a server could be "extracted" also, as you suggest, and either passed or stored in ex. Redis. I'm clearly out of my comfort zone also, but that's what  makes it interesting ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure your case can be implemented with [nginx-clojure](http://nginx-clojure.github.io/). Last year somebody did similar but more complex things with nginx-clojure. And there 's nothing to do with protocol exchange between serverA and ServerB.

1. in nginx content handler, use `hijack!` to get a NginxHttpServerChannel say `ch`, put `ch` into a map with key say `req-uuid`. So we can use `ch` to send response data later. Sends nginx url, req-uuid and other data to ServerA.
2. ServerA sends `nginx-url`, `req-uuid` and other data to ServerB.
3. ServerB sends `req-uuid` and response to nginx by another url which is different with the first step, e.g.  '/asynNotfifyHandler'
4. write another nginx content handler to receive response from ServerB for location '/asynNotfifyHandler'. If nginx worker process is only one,  in this handler gets NginxHttpServerChannel `ch` and uses it to send the response. If we have more than one nginx worker processes  we need use `broadcast!` to broadcast repsonse event and use `on-broadcast!` to get the response event in the nginx worker process who holds the NginxHttpServerChannel `ch` and use it to  send the response to the original client.

[Here](https://github.com/nginx-clojure/nginx-clojure/blob/master/test/clojure/nginx/clojure/ring_handlers_for_test.clj#L139) is an example about channel sub/pub.

BTW We also can use sub/pub from redis instead of  `broadcast!` and `on-broadcast!` from nginx-clojure. e.g. in the first content handler we sub a topic of redis and then server B pub a response message to the same topic of redis. Finally use NginxHttpServerChannel `ch` to  send the response to the original client.

Comment: This looks amazing ! It will take me some time to get to the bottom of it, but I'll accept your answer straight away. Thanks for doing this ! (I may have follow up questions but that looks like a perfect match)

Answer (score 0):

In case of a HTTP request/response scenario, the only thing I can see is through some HTTP server push. The thing is you'll be using TCP connections for, at least, the Client/Nignx communication. You can do it, I guess, with some technologies as "fire and forget" but you will then need to be able to open a new connection to the client to send it new data.

In your first case every service communicate by asking through a request and waiting for a response.

In the second case you could do something proxying requests (without waiting for any response) but with some information about the client to be able to contact it within server B (open a connection).

I don't know which technologies are best for this, but that's the direction I would take.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the input. I've been looking at messages brokers between the servers myself, but I feel the internal discussion between servers should be the easy part. I'm not too sure about opening a new connection. I was hoping to be able to do it on the same response (only one response).

Answer (score 0):

If all of those connections are HTTP requests, unless you implement some kind of [man in the middle](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack) scenario yourself, it does matter to the client.

Basically because of the nature of TCP connections, which HTTP protocol uses transferring the data on the wire, client and server tries to be sure every message is delivered to it's intended target and it is delivered in order.

You could research about TCP protocol to understand its limitations better. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vdc8TCESIg8) video seems like a good start for general overview. At 8:23 in the video it makes an analogy that TCP is kinda like phone conversation, that's why it's hard to change server or the client in mid 'conversation' because it is not designed in that way.

As in phone calls though you can redirect the request so may be you could use HTTP redirects to achieve the desired effect you described.

Comment: I'll have a look at it, thanks. I was under the impression that it was possible, given that the client really talks to a lot of machines before getting to the last, including the nginx proxy.

Comment: In that scenario nginx proxy kind of acts like a translator for somebody else or speaks for someone who cannot reach to the phone :) Again if you can drop the nginx requirement at the last step, I guess it would be trivial to implement what you described with HTTP redirects.